# hadoop hbase environment variables

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cdh4

I tried to setup a 4 node Hadoop cluster using CDH4.7. The cluster is up and running fine and when I submit a word count MR job it completed successfully but when I am submitting an MR job to insert data into HBase it was throwing class not found errors. So I copied hbase jar from hbase lib to hadoop lib. Now it is running fine.

My question is: Is my approach right? I feel I should not copy hbase jar into hadoop lib folder.

Can someone suggest what is the best way? And do we need to set any environment variable or is the cloudera manager doing it itself?

Comment: Could you indicate which class was not found? Could you add a snippet of the exception?

Comment: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.multitableoutputformat.

Comment: I restarted cluster couple of times so job history is not there.